# How to put line in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a loop in this loop i want to populate my array `photos`:

```
   $scope.photos = [];
            var str = data.data.Photos;
            var res = str.split('|');
            angular.forEach(res, function (item) {
                var line = src: 'photos/'+item, desc: item;
                $scope.photos.push(line);
            });
```

i have  errors in the line `var line = src: 'photos/'+item, desc: item;`:

```
 Unexpected token
```

Comment: you forget parenthesis: `{}` around

Comment: do you want to do that? var line = { 'photos/'+item, desc: item};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.forEach(res, function (item) {
                // notice the object literals {}
                var line = { src: 'photos/'+item, desc: item }; 
                $scope.photos.push(line);
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you've got a colon after the `src`, that needs to be in curly brackets because it's an object.

```
var line = {
    src: 'photos/' + item, 
    desc: item
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var line = src: 'photos/'+item, desc: item;
```

TO

```
var line = {
  src: 'photos/'+item, desc: item
};
```